# Problem on installing new software on Eclipse Galileo Platform

Tags: eclipse

I want to install a subversion on my eclipse.

So I went to `Help < Install New Software` and when I pick the "`Galileo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo`" in the "`Work with`" dropdown, it tells me in the main box "`No repository found at http://...`".

It is appearing in my available software sites and when I test the connection it returns me an error saying `Unknown host`.

Can someone please help me, I really need to install that subversion :).
Anna

Comment: Just completed my answer with eclipse proxy settings

Answer (score 4):

As mention in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg26632.html), this could be a proxy issue:

> I assume you mean you used a web browser to get that - if so, is it
>   configured to use a web proxy? If your browser is using a proxy then
>   you need to configure Eclipse to use one too (see the General/Network
>   Connections preference page).

Since [3.5 Galileo](http://ftp.daum.net/eclipse/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/eclipse-news-all.html#workspace_team-proxy-settings-ui), The Network Connection page has been changed to better show the current proxy configuration.

> Now if you go to `Preferences > General > Network Connections`, you are able to see and change Eclipse proxy settings as well as see settings provided by the operating system.
>   If you want to use your browser or Gnome settings, or you have your proxy configured using environmental variables on Linux, you can see them all in this new UI

[image: New proxy settings ui in 3.5]

So to set your proxy, you can follow [this tutorial (How to configure Proxy Settings in Eclipse)](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/)

[image: Proxy Settings]

Comment: Hello VonC, to be honest I don't know how to configure Eclipse to use a proxy. I opened that window you told me, it shows me proxy entries and bypass but I don't know what to do, could you help me with this please?

Comment: Hello VonC, thank you for your help! I am confused because when I set active provider to manual to edit the proxy entries like showed in the tutorial I am not able to check the http button and the edit button is desactivated. It's like I'm not authorized to change this but I have no error message saying this.

Answer (score 3):

The severity of the bug is downgraded, since there is a workaround. Open the eclipse.ini file and add the following
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient

In a few words the above command says that Eclipse can access the web via the *.pac files of the HTTP clients (eg Internet Explorer or Firefox).

To summarize:

Add the above line at the ini file 
ensure that your default system http client (eg Internet Explorer) has proxy settings configured 
Go to Eclipse Window->Preferences->Network Connection and enter the proxy setting here as well 
It should work with this workaround

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which Subversion client you use but neither of them can be installed from the main Galileo site. Follow the instructions on the web page of the Subversion plug-in how to install it.